# Firebase: getting value of a child without knowing its key

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get the value of a child element without knowing the key of that child element? Example data structure below;

```
->cars
-->3282jasjd893j: doors
-->819idid82jkdf: windows
-->fjf842jr8448r: audi
```

I need to get the values "doors", "windows", "audi", without knowing the keys.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share some code.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess magically in what language you are trying to do that ?

Comment: You'll have to get the entire `cars` node, then iterate through its keys.

Comment: So far nothing works really. the best I could do is using Arrays to store the value with [0], [1] and so on keys, but that doesn't allow me to later manipulate the data (when I do know only 1 key). The difficulty is my Keys are user IDs, so at most the system can know only one UID for the given user, while at the same time, I need to access all the values to send push notifications to all UID's Device Tokens (values).

Comment: @GabrielDiez I'm using JavaScript.

Comment: @torazaburo how can I iterate through unknown keys?

Comment: By getting the object (`snapshot.val()`) and iterating through its keys, which you can figure out how to do by googling "iterate over keys of an object". Or, you could use Firebase's [`forEach`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#forEach) on the snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for all your comments and advice. I've got the answer now, and here it is:

```
     let inputArray = [];
     snapshot.forEach(snap => {
     inputArray.push(snap.val());
     return false;
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

While you answered your own question it's probably not going to be a good long term solution.

For example: Suppose you want the doors node and there are 100,000 other nodes. You'll have to load all 100,000 and iterate over them to locate the node. That could exceed the capacity of the device and cause a sluggish experience for the user.

The better answer is to fix the structure:

```
cars
 3282jasjd893j:
     item: doors
 819idid82jkdf:
     item: windows
 fjf842jr8448r:
     item: audi
```

Now you can simply query the cars->item node for 'doors' and it will return the node you want - no iterating necessary!

```
 3282jasjd893j:
     item: doors
```