# Show node name when iterating using ngFor

Tags: angular, firebase, angular5

I am using Angular 5 with AngularFirebase 3. My Firebase db looks like this:

```
-archived
--2018-02-02
----L4Rv1q5KUg549mtDdJJ
-----name:"First"
----L4RiBAhViyOuDJWePYv
-----name:"Second"
--2018-02-03
----L8Mv1q5KUg549mtDdRF
-----name:"Third"
----L56vBAhViyOuDJWeDhl
-----name:"Fourth"
```

I would like to iterate through the children of the "archived" node, showing the names of its children, which would be represented by a list of dates.
How can I accomplish this? Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase: getting value of a child without knowing its key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45607133/firebase-getting-value-of-a-child-without-knowing-its-key)